# Why does Xcode 6.1 always ask for admin password for developer tools each new login

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite, developer-tools

This is annoying. I keep separate accounts for security and don't remember having this problem (feature?) on Mavericks. I am on Yosemite and using Xcode 6.1. Every first time use of Xcode I have to put in my admin password to compile code. After that it runs fine. Is there something I can do in the path to circumvent this? I'm just a simple student writing small programs and hate typing in my password to compile.

But once I do all is good...until I restart.

Comment: Separate accounts for security? You mean, you run as a normal non-admin user? That's not needed. OS X is not (pre-UAC) Windows. You should run as a user who can get admin rights.

Comment: Umm no. There is still possibility of getting malware that can install programs. This way it is NOT possible. Just another layer of security. Perfect example: http://www.zdnet.com/serious-security-flaw-in-os-x-yosemite-rootpipe-7000035372/